# Programming language for graphics, semiconductor layout

Tags: graphics, layout, programming-languages, eda

Is there any programming language to do graphical layout for semiconductor manufacturing?
So far I am using LEdit, an expensive and rudimentary CAD program. As my design is composed of
hundreds of identical cells with only small variations, creating the design programatically sounds like the way to go. Especially as I could take dimensions from a database and have them available for later testing. At the moment, I am giving the designer a list of the sample sizes I need, he draws them, I check them, and then enter them manually into my wafer mapping software.
Output format needs to be dxf or better gerber. The program needs the capability to output many different layers.
I had a look at pgf/tikz, and the programming language side is more than enough for the application, but the output is somewhat limited (no gerber, no layers etc.).
In addition, I need very good resolution (down to nanometers), I haven't tested that yet.

Any other recommendation for a graphics programming language, or library, for wafer layout?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably insufficient for what you're doing, but check out the [Visual Transistor-level Simulation of the 6502 CPU](http://www.visual6502.org) project. They have a system for visually designing the chip and then simulating it.

Online demo: http://www.visual6502.org/JSSim/expert.html?graphics=f (click "Show chip layout")

Comment: They took pictures of the die and then re-generated the layout and the netlist by hand, basically the opposite of what I need to to. Still very impressive, thanks!